# How do I know exactly what type of information Github collects from a visitor?

Tags: privacy, cookies, github

I keep track of the upload bandwidth on every site that I visit, and I've noticed that the most site that uses upload bandwidth is Github.com
every single page that I visit uploads 1.06MB of data.

visiting 3 Github pages results in a total of 3.18MB data uploaded:

[image: Download bandwidth]

Github's remote name:

[image: Github's remote name]

it says in their [Privacy Policy](https://help.github.com/articles/github-privacy-statement/) that they collect my cookies. I don't know what type of data they collect, but is there a way to know what exactly gets uploaded, stop it or take control of what I upload?

This is the heaviest POST command taken from dev tools, as you can see 40 seconds:
[image: inspecting network from dev tools]

I saved that as HAR with content as requested, [here is the file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1b3nD5ogw3Hh6W6eXnf8TorKAkEdLSPME)

Comment: they do indeed POST an unusual amount (compared to piwik or google analytics) of collected info to an endpoint named _stats_, but it's nowhere near 1mb. They also have a somewhat large cookie payload, and that's uploaded with every http request, but i still can't sum those up to anything near 1mb; can you provide more info about what's being sent? Chrome devtools breaks down each connection btw.

Comment: @dandavis, provided more info, downloaded the whole HAR file, line 287 of the file looks fishy, I dunno if that's the reason and why

Answer (score 1):

To see what exactly the site is doing and the details of the sessions, you can use many free tools such as [Glasswire](https://www.glasswire.com/).

I use it to track every network connection on my systems and what files change or what is being uploaded by apps such as Chrome, IE, MS Word or sites. Check it out, it may help you here. This applies to your mobile device as well.

You would be surprised as to what other things the site is doing while you are browsing.

Another tool you can use is a proxy tool (Burp Suite, WireShark, Fiddler etc) that will enable you to intercept requests and responses by the site and you can watch the traffic when you visit the site and forward each request/response individually (some tools will allow you to do that).

Comment: does that tool show you anything that doesn't appear in the browsers built-in network monitoring tools? (aside from msword and other non browsers)

Comment: It will show him similar data, however, in addition to seeing the data that's being posted to the site, he can take action on it as I think that's also important to him: "... but is there a way to know what exactly gets uploaded, stop it or take control of what I upload".

Answer (score 0):

If you are running Chrome:

1. Open the developer tools up on the pages (F12)
2. Got to the network tab
3. Tick preserve log and have a look at the data being sent to-and-from

This way you will actually know what data is being transfer and be able to make a more informed decision on your next steps & look at some controls like a local proxy.

*Note: This sort of data transfer is normal for modern web applications due to their rich features & content.*

Comment: I updated the question with those information

Comment: Cool - but I am not about to analyze your traffic here. If you have a specific question ask away

Comment: This answers what they _can_ collect, not what they _do_ collect.